# Computational Complexity of the Helpmate problem in Chess

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

It is well known that Chess is EXPTIME-Complete.

I am interested in the related "Helpmate" problem. Given an $N$ by $N$ chessboard, is there any sequence of at most $k$ moves that leads to Black's checkmate? To clarify, both players are cooperating to end the game in Black's checkmate.

I could not find any literature discussing the computational complexity of the problem, perhaps I am not searching for the right terms.

Comment: If $k$ is encoded in unary, then the Helpmate problem is in NP, and it should be NP-complete (by emulating some reachability problem).

Comment: A closely related question has been posed here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/58156/what-complexity-class-would-this-version-of-generalized-chess-fall